# What happens if no ram is in a dual CPU riser?

Tags: memory, cpu, dell-precision

I have a Dell precision T5500 with a dual CPU riser. There are 6 slots on the system board and 3 on the second CPU riser. The [Dell recommended configuration](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/wsT5500/en/SM/a_mem.htm) is to divide between the system board and the riser, if there is one.

I'm trying to upgrade from 6GB to 24GB on this machine, so the 6 sticks should be divided as mentioned above. And this was the case in my friend's computer, but not with mine. I had some issues with my ram originally and Dell fixed it under warranty. But when I went to change the ram in my machine, the 6 slots on the system board were filled and there were none in the CPU riser. I installed the 6x4GB ram as recommended and my machine is telling me that DIMM riser 2 is faulty. So, two things:

1. Dell clearly screwed me and rather than replace the riser with the faulty DIMM slot they just moved all of my ram to the system board
2. what is the effect of having all the ram on the system board and none on the riser? What is the effect on performance and is it fine to continue to populate the 24GB of ram like the technician had it?

Thanks for any thoughts on this.